# a weird geometrical interpretation comparing harmonic series to inverse square series

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-interpretation

I was watching [this passage](https://youtu.be/wcjknbmTYOI?list=PL55C7C83781CF4316&t=2810) from a course on history of maths, where harmonic series, inverse square series and other ones are described in the context of the more generic zeta function:

[zeta function, cases n=1 and n=2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBEVD.png)

I was looking for some geometrical interpretation for this, and I found out something weird, when comparing cases n=1 and n=2.

For n=1, I assumed I was starting with a segment of length 1, then adding a half, then a third and so on: the *"resulting segment"* will be infinitely long, as that series (the harmonic one) does not converge.

For n=2, I assumed I was playing the same segment game, but in 2D, adding areas of 1, one fourth, one ninth, and so on: this series (the inverse square one) converges to Pi^2/6.

**Question 1:** Is such an interpretation consistent?

I mean: it brings (apparently) weird results!

Consider the *"resulting segment"*: at each iteration, it is still getting longer, indeed it gets to infinite length, but each "added square" is getting so smaller so fast that the area is not getting infinite: quite counter intuitive.

Indeed, since at each iteration the *"resulting segment"* is getting longer, then the *"added piece"* wouldn't be of zero-length, so why should a square build on that *"added piece"* would be of zero-area?

**Question 2:** how would you explain, geometrically, this behaviour?

Comment: It is not counter-intuitive. There are many examples of infinite-perimeter objects with finite area/volume.

Comment: @cr001 the ones I can think about are fractals, but those are even weirder.
What is "really unexpected here" is a non-zero-length "delivering" a zero-area: it smells like Grassmann numbers, right?

Comment: @ccampisano: A 3-dimensional version of this is the so-called [Gabriel's Horn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel%27s_Horn). It has finite volume but infinite surface area, so you can *fill* it with paint but not *coat* it with paint!

Comment: @Blue well, 1/x is there again... as it is its integral, the soo-slowing-diverging logarithm...

Comment: also see this video and the related comment (@2:05) about "adding what"

https://youtu.be/sD0NjbwqlYw?t=125

Comment: indeed, the log is the integral of 1/x and 1/x is the derivative of the log: the log "diverges but stops at infinity", indeed when x->INF, 1/x is zero, so the log "stops growing at infinity" - that was analytical, geometrically, IMHO, those "zero-areas from non-zero-lengths" really show "where do Grassmann number exist"